# Float forcing min-width on responsive div elements?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-float, width

Hello I have a div with the following CSS

```
{background: purple; max-width: 800px; min-width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left;}
```

Unfortunately it is being forced to min width (if I remove float it is fine).

Is this just what floats do, or have I made an error somewhere?

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/bhY3H/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.
A `div` is a block element and takes 100% width (if no css rule is applied).
**BUT** if you float the div, you are modifing its original flow, it stops behaving like a block, it takes as much width as is needed based on its content (or as much as is specified by min-width/max-width).

So, no, you are not doing anything wrong.

Edit:
If I correctly understand what you are trying to achieve, what happens if you add `width:100%` to your div style?

http://jsfiddle.net/gPTrT/1/

Comment: Sorry I was not trying to achieve anything but I am designing a small tutorial to beginning web design and I came across this on an iframe demo I was doing and I was just curious thank you very much :).